# How to make this subquery not check for null?

Tags: sql

I need a script that returns me unique people.

"CPF" identifiers are unique values, but these data are not always registered. so I would like this subquery not to compare null values. And later I will do the verification by name.

I already have this query, but I need it not to compare null values.

`SELECT* FROM TAB.ORIGEM WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TAB.DESTINO WHERE TAB.DESTINO.CPF = TAB.ORIGEM.CPF )`

Below is an example of the tables and the result I expect.

```
   TAB.ORIGEM
```

| NAME | CPF |
| --- | --- |
| JOAO | 123 |
| MARIA | 321 |
| PAULO |  |

```
 TAB.DESTINO
```

| NAME | CPF |
| --- | --- |
| JOAO | 123 |
| JOANA | 456 |
| JOSE |  |

```
    RESULT
```

| NAME | CPF |
| --- | --- |
| MARIA | 321 |
| PAULO |  |

Comment: Your expected results in below is not a match for your question please explain and clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try join. The result you want:

```
SELECT ORIGEM.* FROM ORIGEM
   LEFT JOIN DESTINO 
   ON DESTINO.CPF = ORIGEM.CPF
   WHERE DESTINO.CPF IS NULL
```

Comment: Still, not knowing about unique constraints bon those tables, I'd rather avoid joins because joins may return multiple rows, while a subquery with EXISTS or IN will not multiply rows.

Comment: Sorry friend, the result of the table was wrong, now I fixed it with what I expect.

Comment: I Edited the second query is what you want. If it was helpful please accept the answer and vote up, thanks.

Comment: @BogdanDincescu Every query is more optimize and performant whit a good join. It depends on you desire for optimization.

Comment: Did not work. The only result of the select was maria.

Comment: You are doing somthing right the second query produces exact result you expect, see: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zA7NZtBoCKVETddFc8TvJ/4

Comment: You are right friend. Mine is not right because instead of null values ​​it was just empty.

Answer (score 1):

Not sur whether I got your requirements right, yet I think you need something like below:

```
select d.*
from destino d
where not exists (
  select 1
  from origem o
  where d.cpf=o.cpf
);
```

Comment: This code is exactly what I already have and put in the question. 
I need it not to compare null values.

Comment: @thund3rbird777, this answer does the opposite, selects from destino, not from origem.

Comment: Right, it selects from destino. But, please tell me where in origem you have JOSE and JOANA, cause I do not see them in the sample data you gave. Therefore, seeing the result you desire, I can see no other way to obtain that result except by selecting from destino.

Comment: Sorry friend, the result of the table was wrong, now I fixed it with what I expect.